# Sort topics by name

Tags: php

I have the following function to work with:

```
function listBrandTopics($params){
  self::_getParam($params,'article_path',Wrapper::basePath().'article/');

  $articles = Array();
  $first_pass = true;
  $count = 0;
  while($result['_links']['next'] || $first_pass){
    $count++;
    $first_pass = false;
    $result = $this->_apiCall(
      Array(
        'path' => '/brands/'.$params['bid'].'/articles',
        'request_param' => Array(
          'per_page' => '100',
          'page' => $count
        )
      )
    )->getBody();
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    $articles = array_merge($articles, array_filter($result['_embedded']['entries'], array($this, '_inSupport')));
  }

  array_walk($articles, Array($this, '_articlesProcessor'));

  $topics = $this->_topicId();

  $info = Array();
  foreach($articles as $article){
    $topic_id = intval($article['topic_id']);
    foreach($topics as $topic){
      $topic_name = trim($topic['name']);
      if($topic_id == $topic['id']){
        $info[$topic_name]['id'] = $topic['id'];
        if(!is_array($info[$topic_name]['articles'])){
          $info[$topic_name]['articles'] = Array();
        }
        array_push($info[$topic_name]['articles'], $article);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  $params['current_brand'] = self::$brand_table[$params['bid']];
  $params['the_data'] = $info;
  $params['the_data_json'] = json_encode($info);
  return $this->_getHtmlTemplate(self::_getParam($params,'template','brandTopics.phtml'),$params);
}
```

It renders a list of topics and their related articles in a support site. 
However, this list of topics is not alphabetically ordered.

I know that $topic['name'] is the name of the topic, but how do I get it to return them in alphabetical order?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: and the framework would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `ksort` to order `$info` by key

After:

```
$info = Array();
foreach($articles as $article){
    ...
}
```

Add:

```
ksort($info);
```

Comment: I see!  I had to sort by key... makes sense. Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Use simple `sort($array)` for alphabetically sorted array.

```
$this->cars = array("bmw", "audi", "opel", "ford");
sort($this->cars);
```

Use `asort($array)` (with sort_flags) if You need to keep key/value association in order.

[sort - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

[asort - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)